# Querystring on Routes in angular

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I would like to configure my routes to be able to accept any integer after its' URL.
For example,

```
/product/id/1242
```

This integer will be accessed by the API factory as a value to be queried by the API.

I have read doc's on setting up routes, but haven't been able to do to it. If i enter a URL with an integer, it just redirects to the login page.

```
angular.module('myapp123.routes', [])


.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
        //$location.path('/product').search('queryStringKey', value).search( ...);
        $stateProvider

            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/core/login/login.html'
                    }
                },
                controller: function ($ionicHistory, $scope) {
                    console.log('Clearing history!');
                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                        historyRoot: true,
                        disableBack: true
                    });
                }


            })

            .state('product', {
                url: '/product',
                when:('/product/id/product_id')
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/components/product/product.html'
                    }
                }


            })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters) This should do the trick. [0-9] limits the product Id to numbers.

```
.state('product', {
                url: '/product/id/{productId:[0-9]}',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/components/product/product.html'
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks- wasn't able to get your version working for some reason.

A work-around I've found, which works:

```
        .state('product', {
        url: '/product/id/:product_id',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/product/product.html',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
            $scope.product_id = $stateParams.product_id;
        }
    })
```